# svg display none or visibility hidden still showing?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I have 3 SVGs one on top of the other:

```
<svg>1</svg>
<svg>2</svg>
<svg>3</svg>
```

To each `path` and `polygon` I have added `.country` and `.shape` then tried `display: none` or `opacity: 0` or `visbility: hidden`

```
.oldmap .country,
.oldmap .shape,
.computer_all .country,
.computer_all .shape {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.newmap .country,
.newmap .shape { 
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

No matter if I use `opacity` or `visibility` or `display none` but I still see the shape on top of the other or underneath.

Only if i remove the other svg work, like:

```
$("svg1").remove();
```

I even tried to set

```
position:absolute; 
left: -99999px;
```

If I hide ALL it's ok but if I am showing 1 then I will still see the rest too

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Paulie_D have I not explained it enough?

Comment: Not really, your question doesn't make sense so there must be something else going on.

Comment: It doesn't male senso to you maybe.  yeah there must be something else going on, I'll find out. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "still see the shape".  By "shape" do you mean the paths and polygons, or do you mean the `<svg>`s?  If the latter, then making elements in the SVG invisible will not make the SVG itself disappear.  Elements in SVG do not collapse in size like HTML elements, such as `<div>`, do.

Comment: Confusing question and it's answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was the way I was using `<svg>` elements. I was overlapping different SVG using `<svg>` tags while I should only use one tag SVG and then insert the shapes with different `<g>` tags in it.

**Wrong:**

```
<svg>1</svg>
<svg>2</svg>
<svg>3</svg>
```

**Correct:**

```
<svg>
 <g></g>
 <g></g>
 <g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The question and answer are still confusing. You could certainly add display:none to any of the svg elements in the "wrong" set to prevent them from being rendered.

Comment: nope.that wouldn't work as explained in the question. If i use 3 svg, you will still see them if the svg elements are on top of each other. I did use all available tags such as display, opacity and visibility as the question says. Only solution, which is also the right way, it's to use one svg tag and inside it many <g> as per the images i want to render